# Multitouch (not gestures!) does not work on Windows Phone devices?

Tags: windows-phone-7, controls, slider, multi-touch, sametime

I read something about it, the standards controls (buttons, etc) do not support  multitouch, you can only use one control at a time. 
I need to use two sliders or drag drops at the same time, among other things, any idea how to do this? I actually have to create the 0? 
How to work with Touch.FrameReported? It works equally DeltaManipulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controls on the phone have the concept of focus. Only one control can have focus at a time. Some controls support multi-touch interaction some do not. It is not posisble to interact with multiple controls at the same time.

If you need to allow the user to manipulate multiple controls at the same time you will have to create your own, new, control which mimics this behavior.

Comment: Interesting point mentioned. Although I did find alternatives .. But they all convert to the creation of new components.